# CSS Media query is off around 100px of what the code is

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a normal media query.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {

}
```

but the style inside only gets applied at around 1085px (according to chrome console).

i checked my viewport it seems fine

any idea why ?

Comment: Post your markup and remaining css, or a plunker if you're willing.

Comment: Can you create a stripped-down example replicable for anybody eager to help? Because almost 100% sure that for most people it will work as intended and there are probably some factors specific to your usecase. Browser version might also help.

Answer (score 2):

Ok turns out im retarded and my browser was zoomed in like 80%

thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: There's also retina-displays to consider, I've seen those cause trouble: https://medium.com/@micjamking/hd-retina-display-media-queries-b5562b5430d6 :: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/